# How can I trigger an Excel macro by hovering a mouse over a cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have not been able to figure out how to run an Excel macro by moving
my mouse over one or more cells in my spreadsheet.

Answer (score 6):

Whilst there is no formal OnMouseOver event, you can put together a VBA hack to get around it. It involves using the HYPERLINK function. There's more detail [here](http://optionexplicitvba.blogspot.co.nz/2011/04/rollover-b8-ov1.html), but in summary:

If you create a new VBA module and then add a User Defined Function to do what you want:

```
Public Function OnMouseOver()
 Sheet1.Range("A2").Value = "You hovered over a cell"
End Function
```

You can then access this via a HYPERLINK call:

```
=IFERROR(HYPERLINK(OnMouseOver(),"Click here"), "Click here")
```

Note that it's wrapped inside an IFERROR to avoid a #VALUE! error message because your function isn't supposed to update a cell (but gets away with it as it's called within HYPERLINK).

Comment: wonky, and brilliant...  I like it!

Answer (score 1):

There is no OnMouseOver in Excel VBA.  I do not believe it can be done.

Comment: you are a man of little faith ;) it has been done and it works beautifully. - http://optionexplicitvba.blogspot.com/2012/06/period-table-of-elements-in-excel.html

Answer (score 1):

The HYPERLINK approach is cute, very shrewd, but still deeply limited. E.g. you can't even have sStr = "" in the UDF code (note, results may vary by Excel version). Much better is a transparent (or even opaque) label, which does have the MouseMove property. Put your code there instead. (I located a video link that nearly perfectly efficiently gives it to you step-by-step in under 4 minutes, with even better comments; if I created a step-by-step guide here you'd spend a half an hour :) . But if I show the link, this post will be deleted [again] by Stack Exchange, so PM me if you want it, and I'll try to respond within a few days.)

Comment: I'll put it this way: hyperlink is the wrong way to do this, even if it's "cool" how it works (partially works, anyway). Instead, just create a label. Put your hover code under its MouseMove event. It's that simple. You may also make the label transparent, which I prefer to do, so that cell contents are displayed rather than the label.

One example of what to code under MouseMove is to create a shape (using .AddShape) with text, then .Delete it after a second or two.

Comment: Though in some sense you are correct, Hyperlink will always be the optimal method. E.G. having 1000 shapes is much more laggy than 1000 hyperlink formulae.

Comment: No, not "always". For one big one, you will quite likely run into limitations with hyperlink(s). And you have control over the size of a shape, but generally not on the size of a cell. Let's say the user is sick of horizontally scrolling and makes the col. width 1. Further, are you sure that that artificiality is faster than using built in constructs? Whether 1 or 1,000? . Building shapes works 100% of the time with precision. I've had many problems with HYPERLINKS. Maybe 1000 shapes really do lag (untested), but with the tradeoffs I really wouldn't say "optimal", certainly not "always".

Comment: ActiveX objects "shapes" are COM objects and thus take a lot of time instantiating and uninstantiating, not to mention render time, and respond to a lot of events not just the ones you are listening for. Formulae do not use COM objects and are executed at the time of use. So yes, forumulae in this case is more optimal. As for your first point, that depends entirely on the application. If you are making MSPaint in Excel then the user won't be doing that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use transparent ActiveX Label (`.BackStyle = fmBackStyleTransparent`, `.Caption = ""`, `.Visible = True`) over the cells and handle it's `MouseMove` event:

```
Private Sub Label1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    Debug.Print Button, Shift, X, Y
End Sub
```

When the Label's `.Visible` property is set to False, the `MouseMove` event will not trigger, but the cells behind it can be clicked (and vice-versa).

Comment: As I indicated.